# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException when migrating webapp to JSF 2.1 & RichFaces 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, transactions, richfaces

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the strange thing here is that I had no problems when using jsf 1.1 / richfaces 3, along with hibernate 3.7 and spring 2.5.

Now that I migrated my front-end to jsf 2.1 / richfaces 4 (hibernate and spring remained the same) the following exception appears when I try to access a collection marked as "lazy=true" in hibernate mapping config:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mu.afs.Afi.cods, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:97)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:225)
at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.isRowAvailable(ListDataModel.java:91)
at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setRowIndex(ListDataModel.java:105)
```

The collection that I try to reach is referenced by a `rich:datatable` in the same xhtml that the `Afi` entity; 
Here is the part of the xhtml that tries to access the collecion upon an ajax request of a master table:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="tableCods" selectionMode="single" 
selection="#{afiBean.codSelected}"
style="width: 100%; height: 100px" 
value="#{afiBean.selectedAfi.cods}" var="cod">
...
<rich:column width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Months"/></f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{cod.months}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column width="80px" style="text-align: right;">
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Cap" /> </f:facet>
    <h:outputText  value="#{cod.cap}">
        <f:convertNumber pattern="######,##0.00" locale="es_AR" />
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column width="200px" style="text-align: center;">
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Class"/></f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{cod.clazz}" />
</rich:column>
...
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

This is part of my application-context.xml:

```
...
    <bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="store*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="read*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

The service that is accessing the `Afi` entity is defined as follow:

```
<bean id="afiService" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.mu.afs.services.AfiService" />
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.mu.afs.services.impl.AfiServiceImpl">
            <property name="afiDao" ref="afiDao" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
    <bean id="afiliadosDao"
    class="com.mu.afs.dao.impl.HibernateAfiDaoImpl"
    parent="hibernateDaoSupport">
</bean>
```

I would really appreciate if someone can throw some light on this issue. I dont know whether is related to a migration issue or if there is a problem with this configuration and was somehow "masked" with a previous version of jsf and richfaces.

I tried to put here any relevant information that I thought it would help without boring and overwhelm the reader, but let me know if something is missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean that lazyinitexception is not thrown with jsf 1.1/richafaces 3 and when u upgrade to jsf 2.1/richfaces 4 you get this excpetion? can you post relevent jsf code meaning component being used.

Comment: Hi Jigar, I didn't get the exception with jsf 1.1/Richfaces 3.1.6. I updated the question with the xhtml part that access the collection. Regards.

Comment: to me it looks like some extra calls added by richfaces extended data table, if you refer to richfaces change log you might be able to find some solution.